# We are having a self-signed certificate in our org which is being used for integration with SAP.

Tags: email, user, certification, notification

Self-signed certificate in our org which is being used for integration with SAP. It works based on two-way SSL with certificate authentication. It is going to expire in few days.
Issue:
Many users in our org getting email notification from Salesforce (noreply@salesforce.com) mentioning the expiring certification.
Question:
Is that possible to restrict the email notifications to few users rather than all users? Is there a place in Salesforce where I can manage the users that should get email notifications? Please advice.

Thanks